# Key Error when extracting the body from email

Tags: python, gmail-api

For some messages, I believe that there is no 'parts' component. I thought the code below covers most messages, but it is still throwing a keyerror: 'data' when trying to get some messages. I have looked through the json result for those messages and they all contain 'data', not sure what's going on. Traceback shows that the keyerror is coming from messages that do contain 'parts'

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gmail.py", line 168, in <module>
final_message_list.append(GetMessage(gmail_service, 'me', message_id))
File "gmail.py", line 150, in GetMessage
message_raw = message['payload']['parts'][0]['body']['data']
```

(within GetMessage)

```
# Pull Raw Message Body from Response, some emails may not contain 'parts'

if 'parts' in message['payload']:
  message_raw = message['payload']['parts'][0]['body']['data']
else:
  message_raw = message['payload']['body']['data']
```

Comment: We can't know what's happening here unless we can reproduce this error. Can you try printing `message` right before the if statement so you can see what is inside `message` when it fails.

Comment: I figured it out, this failed message actually has another level called 'parts' that then contains 'body' and 'data' - what's the best way to account for these differences?

Comment: If you found a solution try and add your own answer. People in the future may have the same problem. As for how to account for the differences, only reading the specs can solve that.

Comment: @BoppreH No actually, I haven't. For whatever reason, the structure in the returned JSON has a few different setups, such that the placement of the "Body/Data" that contains the actual body of the message can be a little different in each message...my question is what's the best way to attack this? Perhaps some kind of iterating loop that goes down the tree to find body/data until it returns something? I'm not sure, if anyone has any better ideas that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, this is the best I've been able to do for now, if anyone has a better solution please post.

It looks like the message in question that caused the failure has an attachment, and perhaps the attachment is what messes up the structure of the message a bit. I've been able to see that the mimeType within 'Parts' is different (multipart/alternative) for attachment messages than it is for non-attachment messages (text/plain). Thus, I've been able to cover this case by just putting an 'if' statement before I try to parse out the message body, as shown below.

```
 if 'parts' in message['payload']:

  if message['payload']['parts'][0]['mimeType'] == 'multipart/alternative':
    message_raw = message['payload']['parts'][0]['parts'][0]['body']['data']    
  else:
    message_raw = message['payload']['parts'][0]['body']['data']   

 else:
  message_raw = message['payload']['body']['data']
```

Comment: But the message_raw still a raw data. How can I see the message body in a human readable format?